# Stuck on a level for think different

Tags: think-different

I'm stuck on a level. I have tried guessing a few numbers but can't see a pattern. Can anyone solve the following sequence?

10,20,22,44,46,92,94,??

Comment: What have you tried so far? At first glance, it looks like the pattern is double then add 2, which promptly repeats.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 188. The patterns is as follows: times 2, plus 2:

```
a * 2 = b + 2 = c * 2 = d + 2 ....
```

So you have:
10 * 2 = 20
20 + 2 = 22
22 * 2 = 44
44 + 2 = 46
46 * 2 = 92
92 + 2 = 94
94 * 2 = 188